# appending a child using foreach

Tags: javascript, arrays

Supposed I have a response of

[image]

And I loop through the array via

```
    response.data.aTweets.forEach(element => {
        //console.log(element);
        element.pics.forEach(pic => {
            var image = new Image();
            image.height = 180;
            image.classList.add('mt-2','rounded','mr-2', 'w-100');
            image.src    = pic;
            oHome.oImageRow1.appendChild(image); //append to image row one if length is <= 2
            oHome.oImageRow2.appendChild(image); //append to image row one if length is > 2
        });
        oHome.oTweetContainer.appendChild(oHome.oClone);
    });
```

and this my oImageRow1 and oImageRow2

```
<div class="row" id="image_row_one">

</div>

<div class="row" id="image_row_two">

</div>
```

How can I append to image row one if the length of the element.pics is greater than 2

I tried to use the element.pics.length however it is constant. I think i might need a counter or something

Comment: use `if/else` is the regular way

Comment: forEach has an index parameter that you can use to calculate with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: use `element.pics.forEach((pic, i) => {` second parameter will be your counter use if to check.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```js
 response.data.aTweets.forEach(element => {
        //console.log(element);
        element.pics.forEach(pic => {
            var image = new Image();
            image.height = 180;
            image.classList.add('mt-2','rounded','mr-2', 'w-100');
            image.src = pic;
            
            element.pics.length > 2 ? oHome.oImageRow2.appendChild(image) : oHome.oImageRow1.appendChild(image);
        });
        oHome.oTweetContainer.appendChild(oHome.oClone);
    });
```